# Wix Toolset - Reference Binary - Separate wxs file

Tags: reference, binary, wix, installation, sequence

I am starting to use Wix toolset to create installers and I am trying to get to grips with it.

I have a large `product.wxs` file which holds everything and I am trying to split it up into separate wxs files (fragments) for binaries, properties and sequencing.

I have been able to split up the properties by including a "PropertyRef" of one of the properties within `product.wxs` to allow all of the properties to be referenced, however I am not sure on how to do this for binaries and sequencing?

Any advise in this area please?

Thank you for any assistance on this.

Reference links:-
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-reference-a-wxs-file-from-another-td7334084.html

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-reference-a-wxs-file-from-another-td7334084.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround - not sure if this is the correct way to do this but it works.

Within the separate wxs files (binaries, sequencing etc.) create a property and then reference this property within the main product.wxs file

So you would create a dummy property as below within the separate binaries wxs file

```
<Property Id="BinaryRef" Value="1"></Property>
```

then reference this property within the main product.wxs file as below

```
<PropertyRef Id="BinaryRef"/>
```

Referencing this property from the binaries wxs file will then pull all the rest of the data in, this can be done for any separate wxs file.